# I have multiple overloads of the * operator in a template class. Why do I get different results when I put the declarations in different order?

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading, friend

I'm having a class which needs to have multiple overloads of the * operator. Some of these need to be declared as friends so I can have the class type as second argument. This is an example of a class which encounters the problem I'm about to present:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Example;

template<typename T>
Example<T> operator*(T value, Example<T> obj);

template<typename T>
class Example
{
private:
    T m_data;
public:
    Example(T);
    friend Example operator*<T>(T, Example);
    Example operator*(const T& other);

};

template<typename T>
Example<T> operator*(T value, Example<T> obj)
{
    return value * obj.m_data;
}

template<typename T>
Example<T>::Example(T data) :m_data(data) { }

template<typename T>
 Example<T> Example<T>::operator*(const T& other)
{
    return Example(m_data * other.m_data);
}
```

This works but If I change:

```
template<typename T>
class Example
{
private:
    T m_data;
public:
    Example(T);
    friend Example operator*<T>(T, Example);
    Example operator*(const T& other);
};
```

with

```
template<typename T>
class Example
{
private:
    T m_data;
public:
    Example(T);
    Example operator*(const T& other);
    friend Example operator*<T>(T, Example);
};
```

I start getting a bunch of errors even though all I'm doing is swapping those 2 lines containing the declarations of the operator overloads. Can you explain me what is going on here? This makes no sense to me.

Code that generated error:

```
Example<int> a(2);
2 * a;
```

Errors:

> ```
> unexpected token(s) preceding';'  
> syntax error missing':' before '<'  
> 'operator*': redefinition: previous definition was 'function'  
> 'operator*': looks like a function but there is no parameter list.  
> '*': uses 'Example<int>' which is being defined  
> '*': friend not permitted on data declarations
> ```

https://godbolt.org/z/j4zYTP8n7

Comment: better include the error message in the question. And the question would be more clear if you post the code that does cause the errors (and then explain what to change to make it work)

Comment: In your member `operator*`, shouldn't `return Example(m_data * other.m_data);` be `return m_data * other;` to be consistent with your non-member `operator*`? The order of the operands shouldn't affect the result

Comment: It should be: `template<typename U>  friend Example<U> operator*(U, Example<U>);` this fixes issue, but I wonder why first version compiles second doesn't (on all major compilers).

Comment: For the sample instantiation posted the conversion constructor is used in both instances. So it is at best ambiguous. The error messages doesn't make much sense though. The keyword `explicit` should probably help to diagnose this.

Comment: @MarekR I tried to change the declaration as you suggested but I still get errors if I put the friend declaration underneath the other one.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7jKeGMWK5

Comment: If I change the order of the two declarations, It still wouldn't work. https://godbolt.org/z/Wr7xqorrb

Comment: @stack_overflow_nickname do you know what `#ifndef ALT` does? Note respective compiler options `-DALT` (`/D ALT`). https://godbolt.org/z/x97sYb94j

Comment: @MarekR No, I've actually never used those before

Comment: It allows alter file content. Now depending if option `-DALT` (`/D ALT`) is used or not specific version of file is used. In your case code it uses code with different order of function declaration (it happens before compilation process). This way both versions are checked with single source file and multiple compilers setup.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different things named `operator*` in your code. There is the function template, which you declare before `Example`, and the member function of `Example`. The syntax `operator*<T>`, a template specialization, is only valid when `operator*` refers to the template, but not to the member function. In your first declaration, where the `friend` comes before the member function, the `operator*` member function has not been declared at the point where the compiler sees `operator*<T>`, so it resolves the name to the function template declared before `Example` and everything is fine (the specific specialization `operator*<T>` becomes a `friend` of each `Example<T>`).

```
template<typename T>
Example<T> operator*(T value, Example<T> obj); // <-\ ...finds a template, so no syntax error
                                               //   |
template<typename T>                           //   |
class Example {                                //   |
    T m_data;                                  //   |
public:                                        //   |
    Example(T);                                //   |
    friend Example operator*<T>(T, Example);   // >-/ looking up this name...
    Example operator*(const T& other);
};
```

Do it the other way and instead `operator*<T>` is taken to refer to the member function, which is not a template, and you get a syntax error (specifically, I think it's trying to somehow interpret it as `operator* < T >` where the `<` and `>` are the actual less-than/greater-than operators).

```
template<typename T>
class Example {
    T m_data;
public:
    Example(T);
    Example operator*(const T& other);       // <-\ ...does not find a template; ouch!
    friend Example operator*<T>(T, Example); // >-/ looking up this name...
};
```

Comment: `template specialization` needs `template<>` prefix which he does not have!

Comment: @MarekR [It does not.](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#example-8) You need the `template<>` prefix to declare a specialization of a template, but we're not really doing that.

Comment: you have written about "template specialization" I just quote you, and point out question do not have it. So I agree with you: "we're not really doing that". Also this link of yours do not do that either so I have no idea what was the point.

Answer (score 1):

With your help I've reached the following solution. I was also able to get rid of the redundancy of declarations from the first lines. This is the final product:

```
template<typename T>
class Example
{
private:
    T m_data;
public:
    Example(T);

    Example operator*(const T& other);

    template<typename T>
    friend Example<T> operator*(T, Example<T>);
};

template<typename T>
Example<T> operator*(T value, Example<T> obj)
{
    return value * obj.m_data;
}

template<typename T>
Example<T>::Example(T data) :m_data(data) { }

template<typename T>
Example<T> Example<T>::operator*(const T& other)
{
    return Example(m_data * other.m_data);
}
```

Comment: Is my understanding correct that this will make, for instance, `operator*(double, Example<double>)` a `friend` of `Example<int>`? Is that necessary? (Obviously non-member `operator*` can be written without needing to be a `friend` by changing its implementation to use member `operator*`, but assuming we wanted to keep the `friend` version but make it more parsimonious.)

Comment: @NathanPierson I believe what you say is right, and maybe that could become inconvenient. If you have any better idea, by all means, do tell.

Comment: I thought that question was "WHY?", not "how to fix code?". This answer is just my comment under a question.

Comment: The question was why, but finding some useful code seems a bonus. Why wouldn't we share it?